# Set width dynamically in .each - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in setting width of an element dynamically. I have multiple .each loops and then I append an element which should have calculated width. This is the code I have

```
$.each(roomsArray, function(index, row) {
       $.each(datesArray, function (dateIndex, date) {
           $.each(row.calendarList, function(calendarIndex, cal) {
                if(cal.roomId == row.id && new Date(cal.dateFrom).toDateString() == new Date(date).toDateString()) {
                    var cellElements = $(".day[data-date='" + new Date(date).toDateString() + "']");

                    $.each(cellElements, function (indexElement, element) {
                        if (element.parentElement.attributes[1].value == cal.roomId) {
                            var to = new Date(cal.dateTo);
                            var from = new Date(cal.dateFrom);
//the width should be 44*numOfDays
                            var numOfDays = Math.ceil((to.getTime() - from.getTime()) /  (1000 * 3600 * 24));

                            console.log(element);

                            $(element).append(`
//This element needs to take the width
                                <div id="` + element.attributes[0].value + element.attributes[1].value + `" class="draggable"></div>
                            `);
//This is just something I tried to do, but it doesnt work. 
                             $('#' + element.attributes[0].value + element.attributes[1].value).css('width', 44 * numOfDays + 'px');
                        }
                    });
                }
           });
       })
    });
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrrCh/

I think you are trying to run the Javascript before the HTML is loaded. Bind it to the document.ready and it should be working

```
window.onload=function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('chart');
    elem.style.width = 70 + "%";

}
```

Comment: It is inside the $(document).ready(function( {})... Just have a ton of code and I copied just this part

Comment: have you tried what i shared with you.replace your code line below of "//This is just something I tried to do, but it doesnt work. " with what i shared inside window.onload function. NOTE : take element object correctly.